# Regex match words without alphabet

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to match all words  that doesn't include alphabet `[a-zA-Z]` init.

**Pass cases**

- Some Name
- Another3 [VLT]
- Also! (This)

**Fail cases**

- Not 42 this
- This is wrong (!)
- Wrong #!

I tried this regex `/\b[^a-zA-Z ]+\b/` but it fails for some cases

Comment: Hm, it all depends on how exact and specific you want to be. If you just want to make sure that every whitespace delimited set of characters at least contains an alphabet, then try [`^\S*?[a-zA-Z]\S*(?:\s\S*?[a-zA-Z]\S*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/M42oci/1). Now offcourse, this can get much more complicated if indeed you want to pass exact patterns like `[abc]`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? `Some Name` has 2 words with chars a-zA-Z Why should that match, and do you want 2 separate matches?

Comment: The big question: Can a word contain spaces?

Comment: Tip: A `word boundary` (`\b`) will also match between numbers and space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\S)[^A-Za-z\s]+(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rPzGW2/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - left-hand whitespace boundary
- `[^A-Za-z\s]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace and ASCII letters (use `[^\p{L}\s]+` to support all Unicode letters if supported)
- `(?!\S)` - right-hand whitespace boundary.